# Combining data from two PostgreSQL tables into one

Tags: postgresql

I would like to extract data from two different tables to get the following - see attached image [The data that I am after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtL8T.jpg). My aim is to get the count of depositors independent of the active players per day. That is, if a player deposited but did not play, i would still want the player to be counted.

I am using the following code but the results are not what i am after - see image [The data that I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtL8T.jpg). I am only getting one calendar_date (2017-01-01) per row per country. The data is being summed up for both dates into one & there is another row of data (under depositors & Total_Deposit_Amount) which does not belong to any country. This data should be distributed between the respective countries.

```
--temporary table for start_date
WITH Temp_Start_Date as 
(
select CAST('2017-01-01' AS date)
),

--temporary table for end_date

Temp_End_Date as 
(
select CAST('2017-01-03' AS Date)
),

--temporary table for calendar date
Temp_Calendar_Date as 
(
    SELECT  1 as LinkDate
        ,calendar_date::date from generate_series('2017-01-01',
            CURRENT_DATE -212, '1 day'::interval) calendar_date

),

--temporary table for bet_transactions
Temp_bet_transactions AS
(
        SELECT  BT.account_id
        , P.username
        , CASE 
            WHEN P.country_code = '1' then '1' 
            WHEN P.country_code = '2' then '2'
            WHEN P.country_code = '3' then '3'
            WHEN P.country_code = '4' then '4'
            WHEN P.country_code = '5' then '5'
            WHEN P.country_code = '6' then '6'
            ELSE '7'
        END AS Country
        , 1 AS LinkDate
        , SUM(CAST(CAST(money_amount_cents AS DECIMAL (18,2))/100 AS DECIMAL (18,2))) AS Turnover
    FROM    accounts A
    JOIN    players P ON A.player_id = P.id
    JOIN    ONLY bet_transactions BT ON A.id = BT.account_id
    WHERE   BT.created_at >= (SELECT * FROM Temp_Start_Date) 
        AND BT.created_at < (SELECT * FROM Temp_End_Date)
        AND BT.status = 'accepted'
        AND amount_cents <> 0
    GROUP BY
        1, 2, 3
),

--temporary table for depositors
Temp_depositors AS
(
    SELECT  account_id
        , 1 AS LinkDate
        , SUM(CAST(CAST(money_amount_cents AS DECIMAL (18,2))/100 AS DECIMAL (18,2))) AS Total_Deposit_Amount
    FROM    deposit_transactions D
    WHERE   D.created_at >= (SELECT * FROM Temp_Start_Date) 
            AND D.created_at < (SELECT * FROM Temp_End_Date)
            AND status = 'accepted'
    GROUP BY
        1, 2
)

--get result
SELECT  TCD.calendar_date
    , BT.country
    , COUNT(DISTINCT BT.account_id) AS Active_Players
    , COUNT(DISTINCT DT.account_id) AS Depositors
    , SUM(DT.Total_Deposit_Amount) AS Total_Deposit_Amount
    , SUM(BT.Money_Bet) AS Turnover
FROM    Temp_Calendar_Date TCD
JOIN    Temp_bet_transactions BT ON TCD.LinkDate = BT.LinkDate
FULL OUTER JOIN Temp_depositors DT ON BT.account_id = DT.account_id
GROUP BY
    1,2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

I am to low on reputation to make comments so I have to ask here.

This is generally because `Temp_Calendar_Date` contains **only one row** (with `2017-01-01`) and you're grouping after this.

It would much easier if you would provide some inserts to generate test data.

BTW, What is `LinkDate`? Wy this is always equal to `1`?

Comment: Linkdate is being used as a dummy column to group the data by the calendar date